# Navigation cmd_vel and TwistStamped

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've set up the navigation stack on my robot. The issue is `move_base` is publishing the velocity commands on `cmd_vel` whose message is of type `Twist`, but my robot is subscribing to a topic called `base_velocity` whose message is of type  `TwistStamped`. So as I understand, only [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) wouldn't do the work. What can I do to remap topics of different message types.

Thanks

**Answer:** So I wrote the node below that converts `cmd_vel` messages to `base_velocity,`

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
    import rospy
    from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist, TwistStamped
    
    import time
    
    
    def callback(cmdVelocity):
    
        baseVelocity = TwistStamped()
        
        baseVelocity.twist = cmdVelocity
        
        now = rospy.get_rostime()
        baseVelocity.header.stamp.secs = now.secs
        baseVelocity.header.stamp.nsecs = now.nsecs
    
        baseVelocityPub = rospy.Publisher('base_velocity', TwistStamped, queue_size=10)
        baseVelocityPub.publish(baseVelocity)
    
        
    def cmd_vel_listener():
    
        rospy.Subscriber("cmd_vel", Twist, callback)
    
        rospy.spin()
            
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        rospy.init_node('cmd_vel_listener', anonymous=True)
        cmd_vel_listener()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192682/navigation-cmd_vel-and-twiststamped/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create a simple node that subscribes to the `/cmd_vel` topic, creates a `TwistStamped` message with the `/cmd_vel` info + the stamp and publishes to the `/base_velocity` topic.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2